# Auth::attempt Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel-5

Basically I get a user of username@company type and after I explode I search the data of connection of the specific database of the client.

After changing the database at runtime, I try to log in but Auth :: attempt does not work.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\SysClient;
use App\User;
use Config;
use Hash;
use DB;
```

...

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $data = explode('@', $request->username);
    $username = $data[0];
    $alias = $data[1];
    $password = $request->password;
    //$password = Hash::make($request->password);

    $client = SysClient::where('alias', $alias)->first();

    $connection = [
        "driver" => $client->driver,
        "host" => $client->host,
        "port" => $client->port,
        "database" => $client->database,
        "username" => $client->username,
        "password" => $client->password,
        "unix_socket" => $client->unix_socket,
        "charset" => $client->charset,
        "collation" => $client->collation,
        "prefix" => $client->prefix,
        "prefix_indexes" => $client->prefix_indexes,
        "strict" => $client->strict,
        "engine" => $client->engine
    ];

    $request->session()->put('current_database', $connection); // save $connection in session

    Config::set('database.connections.default', $connection); // set new connection
    DB::purge('default'); // purge connection settings
    DB::reconnect('default'); // reconnect database

    //dd(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()); //it works!

    $credentials = [
        'username' => $username, // string
        'password' => $password, // string
        'active' => 1
    ];

    //dd(User::all()); //it works!

    //So far everything works, the error happens when executing the next line

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        dd('Authentication passed...');
    } else {
        dd('fail');
    }

}
```

I expected Auth::attempt to return true or false, but it does not seem to want to work with the updated database connection.

Comment: can you post your full error stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem but I still do not know how to fix it.

Session control in Google App Engine needs to be done by database and not by file.

The system loads the database "main" and writes the session to the "sessions" table. When the connection is changed the session does not exist in the new database and when laravel tries to modify/delete the table record for the session it does not find it and returns the error:

"Call to a member function prepare() on null" on \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

on line 479:

```
$statement = $this->getPdo()->prepare($query);
```

putting this in the previous line(478)

```
dd($query, $bindings);
```

I get:

```
"update `sessions` set `payload` = ?, `last_activity` = ?, `user_id` = ?, `ip_address` = ?, `user_agent` = ? where `id` = ?"

array:6 [▼
  0 => "YTo0OntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiNTVkSHFUS0tFeDF3SDhBeGRTN1E1UWJhblA2M3lhaGdueVNNSGFYRCI7czo5OiJfcHJldmlvdXMiO2E6MTp7czozOiJ1cmwiO3M6Mjc6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6 ▶"
  1 => 1562871843
  2 => null
  3 => "127.0.0.1"
  4 => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
  5 => "OuxA1KMCkIPnobRHB626VlyivPFI6aW860CvEs7s"
]
```

I can not work with sessions on files in Google App Engine, they need to stay in the database. The question then may be how to move the session from a table in the database "main" to a table in the client database. Or if it is possible to end the session in the "main" database and start a new session in the client database.